# How do I treat warnings as errors in specific Java files?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a Java project that has a lot of compiler warnings.  I can't fix all of them at once, but I would like to ensure that each file that becomes warning-free remains warning-free.  Is there a way to turn warnings into errors in specific files or packages?  I'm interested in generating the errors with either Eclipse or javac.

Comment: The eclipse default warnings and errors should be fine for most users, so I don't recommend you change them. Better to deal with warnings as you have time and errors when they happen. The settings are under project properties/Java Compiler/Errors Warnings.

Comment: @Nicholas Unless Eclipse has changed, such that its default warning settings are equivalent to `javac -Xlint`, I must disagree.  At the very least, I would amend your statement to say “The eclipse default warnings and errors should be fine for most beginner users.”  Last time I looked, Eclipse hid all warnings related to generics by default.

Comment: @Nicholas I have looked at Eclipse's "Errors/Warnings" dialog, but I didn't see anything that would help me remove warnings from a project incrementally.  I would like to continue fixing warnings as I encounter them but be able to mark a file as having no warnings once I fix the last one.  That way I would notice if I added a warning to one of those files, which is especially important if the warning appears far from the edit.

Comment: @VGR Eclipse warns against generics. Perhaps you need to update your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings:
Here you could switch any Warning entry to Error. Beware some entries may be hidden by expandable panels, so make sure you expand them all.

[image]

At the top right corner you can also select "*Configure Project Specific Settings..*" if you want to apply this configuration to only a project and not to all projects by default. Alternatively, you can achieve the same by right click on the concerned project > Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings entry.

Hence, this will be applied to either the whole workspace or just a project, but not to specific files or packages, you don't have this granularity in Eclipse.

This should help you to achieve it, although it might become time and effort consuming to keep it clean, but that's another story.

Moreover, from the Problems view you can create a new Problem View, then from its menu (right top corner of the view, as shown by the picture below), you can configure it.
[image]

Once created a new Problems View, you can again use the same menu and select the *Configure Contents..* entry. From there, you can create a New configuration (see picture below) and define it only for the select element (if you previously selected the concerned class or package), and define whether you want to see any of Errors, Warnings, Info and from which category.

[image]

This configuration could help you out to narrow down and filtering errors and warnings on a specific package or class as a complement or as a different solution/approach than the description above.

Final note: I used Eclipse Mars to try it out, but the functionality should be there since many past versions.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting filtering the "Problems" view.  I ended up creating a working set containing the files that should be warning-free.  New warnings stand out even though they are not treated as errors.  I exported the working set to a .psf file in order to edit it more easily and use version control.  The only problem is that I have to re-import the file and then select the working set in "Configure Contents" every time I modify it.